# deploy wso2esb in docker container with kubernetes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers, kubernetes

can someone help with how to deploy wso2esb in docker container with kubernetes?

currently im running only one node/master at local machine with ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

if im running with this

```
sudo docker run --name esb isim/wso2esb
```

it instantly trigger the service inside the container

but if im running with this

```
kubectl run esb1 --image=isim/wso2esb
```

the container just run, without trigger the service inside the container

btw im using isim/wso2esb from docker hub

hope someone can help me..

Comment: If you run `kubectl logs esb1` what output do you see?

Comment: OMG!! thx!! the IP from logs is different from the RC i expose. i connect from the IP that was given from service. thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, it looks like you were connecting to the wrong IP address, which you discovered by running `kubectl logs esb1`.

In general, you can follow the [Kubernetes Debugging FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ) when you see an issue like this to see if it is a common problem that has already been documented.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer!!, yeah it was, i connect to the wrong IP.
now i already can connect to the IP from the log.

but how about i wanna expose my RC to the public?
where it got another IP for the RC which is a Cluster IP?

if i use the IP from the logs that mean the traffic go straight to the pods without go to Service first right?
correct me if im wrong.
thx before!!

Comment: If you want to expose your pods you should create a service rather than using the pod IP. A service will have a cluster IP, which is a stable virtual IP within the cluster that will reach the pods regardless of which node they are running on.

Comment: If you want to expose the service externally, you should check out the "Publishing services - service types" section of http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html.